# trying to understand toggleClass()

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code, which adds/removes classes:

```
 clearAndSetLogin: function (row) {

    if ($j('#leademails tr').is('.waslogin'))
        $j('#leademails tr.waslogin').removeClass('waslogin');

    $j('#leademails tr.islogin').removeClass('islogin').addClass('waslogin');     
    row.addClass('islogin');   
 },
```

can I do the same with toggleClass() ? if so, why that would be more efficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` part is not needed

so your code needs to be

```
$j('#leademails tr.waslogin').removeClass('waslogin');
$j('#leademails tr.islogin').removeClass('islogin').addClass('waslogin');
row.addClass('islogin');
```

the `toggleClass` will not help in this case as you are operating on different elements in each line (*and my assumption is that you have multiple `tr` elements under the `#leademails`, and you do not all of them getting the `islogin` or `waslogin` class*).

Answer (score 2):

**No, `toggleClass` won't do exactly the same thing** (at least not without having most of your existing code there anyway).

If we take the following code (which won't do what you want):

```
clearAndSetLogin: function (row) {
    $j('#leademails tr').toggleClass(".waslogin");
    $j('#leademails tr').toggleClass(".islogin");
},
```

and work through it line by line a call to `clearAndSetLogin` would **add** waslogin if it isn't there, remove it if it was and do the same thing for islogin. What you have in your code only adds waslogin if it currently islogin.

You could do the .islogin part with toggleClass if you wanted.

Comment: this will add the `.waslogin` and `.islogin` to all `tr` elements under `#leademails`.

Comment: @Gaby, That was my point. Hence the no, toggleClass **won't** do the same thing. I guess I didn't make it clear enough. I'll bold more things :)

Comment: not your fault.. i must had fast-read through it and gave emphasis on the code-part ... Your disclaimer are clear enough :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at jQ's API, http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

but yes, this should be what your looking for:

```
clearAndSetLogin: function (row) {
    $j('#leademails tr').toggleClass(".waslogin");
    $j('#leademails tr').toggleClass(".islogin");
},
```